# Why is the Wilcoxon test not significant for this data?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

The 2 data.frame `count` values look quite significantly different to me, so I'm wondering why the output of the Wilcoxon test is not "significant."

Here is my data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c("Day 1", "Day 1"), count = c(59L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(time = c("Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2"), count = c(1L, 207L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The p-value calculated is: p-value = 0.8353

The code I ran for the test is:

```
wilcox.test(df1$count, df2$count, alternative = 'two.sided', exact = FALSE)
```

Comment: what is the test you ran with this data?

Comment: (i.e. - what was the line of code to do the Wilcox test?)

Comment: Since your provided data has 4 groups, you could not have used this data for a Wilcox test unless you eliminated two of the groups.

Comment: @dcarlson, there are only 2 groups?

Comment: Apologies, I shared the wrong code. I've edited the original post now to include the two data frames I used.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting results from statistical mdoels, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: In the example data above there are only 2 points for df1, thus I don't believe there is a large enough sample to make a fair comparison to df2 thus a high p-value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is part of what `?wilcox.test` will give you:

> if both ‘x’ and ‘y’ are given and ‘paired’ is ‘FALSE’,
> a Wilcoxon rank sum test (equivalent to the Mann-Whitney test: see
> the Note) is carried out.  In this case, the null hypothesis is
> that the distributions of ‘x’ and ‘y’ differ by a location shift
> of ‘mu’ and the alternative is that they differ by some other
> location shift (and the one-sided alternative ‘"greater"’ is that
> ‘x’ is shifted to the right of ‘y’).

Note that `df1` has only *two* entries, while `df2` has only eight, and (importantly!) they overlap in range - specifically, the entire range of `df1$count` is contained in the range of `df2$count`.

There is simply not enough signal there to reject the null hypothesis that the distributions do not differ in location.

---

Put conversely, for sample sizes of 2 and 8, your distributions would need to be completely disjoint for the Wilcoxon test to reject the null:

```
> wilcox.test(1:2, 3:10)

        Wilcoxon rank sum exact test

data:  1:2 and 3:10
W = 0, p-value = 0.04444
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Of course, since this is a rank-based test, if they samples do not overlap, it does not matter how far apart they are:

```
> wilcox.test(1:2, 4:11)

        Wilcoxon rank sum exact test

data:  1:2 and 4:11
W = 0, p-value = 0.04444
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

(Note how both the test statistic and the p value are identical to the previous case.)

---

You write that "The 2 data.frame `count` values look quite significantly different to me", but (1) differences in distributions is not what the Wilcoxon test looks at. As above, it looks at *differences in location* between two samples. If you want to check whether two samples are different "as such", you could try something based on tabulating the data, perhaps with a $\chi^2$ test. However, (2) your sample is also much too small for that.